# How do you set the creation and modification date for a file in AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm creating files in an AIR application like this:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myFile");
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeUTFBytes(data);
stream.close();
```

This leaves the creation and modification dates on created files blank. Is there are way to add this information?

Comment: I've never seen that, the creation and modification dates are properly set on my machine. What OS/Air version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Creation and modification dates are generally handled by the OS and not set by applications unless they deal specifically with that information (e.g., `rsync`).

What OS are you seeing this behavior on?